# Tracking levels in recursive function calls

Tags: php, recursion

I want to write a set of functions that return an indented string. From a structure like this `table([tr([td([1,2,3]),td([4,5,6])])]);`, I want to create a structure like this:

```
<table>
--<tr>
----<td>1</td>
----<td>2</td>
----<td>3</td>
--</tr>
--<tr>
----<td>4</td>
----<td>5</td>
----<td>6</td>
--</tr>
</table>
```

(I don't actually want to use `-`, but spaces, but I'm just using the hyphens for development/debugging.)

This is my script:

```
<?php

function tag($tag, $content) {

  static $depth = 0;

  $depth++;

  echo "tag: '$tag', depth: $depth\n";

  if ( is_array($content) ) {
    $output = str_repeat("--", $depth);
    foreach ( $content as $part ) {
      $output .= tag($tag, $part);
    }
    $depth--;
    return $output;
  }

  $output = str_repeat("--", $depth);
  $depth--;

  return "$output<$tag>$content</$tag>\n";
}

function table($content) {
  return tag(__FUNCTION__, $content);
}
function tr($content) {
  return tag(__FUNCTION__, $content);
}
function td($content) {
  return tag(__FUNCTION__, $content);
}

echo table([tr([td([1,2,3]),td([4,5,6])])]);
```

And this is my output. The first part is debugging:

```
tag: 'td', depth: 1
tag: 'td', depth: 2
tag: 'td', depth: 2
tag: 'td', depth: 2
tag: 'td', depth: 1
tag: 'td', depth: 2
tag: 'td', depth: 2
tag: 'td', depth: 2
tag: 'tr', depth: 1
tag: 'tr', depth: 2
tag: 'tr', depth: 2
tag: 'table', depth: 1
tag: 'table', depth: 2
```

And here's the resulting structure:

```
------<table>------<tr>------<td>1</td>
----<td>2</td>
----<td>3</td>
</tr>
----<tr>------<td>4</td>
----<td>5</td>
----<td>6</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

What I've realized is that PHP is processing the innermost expressions, the `td()`s, first, then the `tr()`s, and finally the `table()`, and that's why the indentation is not happening the way I want.

I've been trying to debug this code over and over, and my brain is now short circuiting. Is there any way I can know how 'deep' I am in the structure, so I can properly indent the tags?

Also, my line breaking is broken, and I don't have a clue as to why or how to start debugging. So, bonus points for fixing that also.

I realize that this isn't a practical solution, and there are different ways to get my desired output, but I've gone this far down the path and now I want to understand how this could work, for the sake of it.

Comment: @raveenanigam It's either the numerical elements of the arrays (1,2,3,etc), or the string `td`, `tr`, or `table`.

Answer (score 0):

When you call `A(B(), C())`, the parameters for `A()` are evaluated first, this is why the execution order is `B, C, A`. By the time, you call `td()`, the function has **no chance** to know its depth because it depends on context that is added later in the execution.

> I've gone this far down the path and now I want to understand how this could work, for the sake of it.

It won't. At least not with a call like this `echo table([tr([td([1,2,3]),td([4,5,6])])]);` - I suggest to separate building of the hierarchy from generating actual output.

Or you could start with actually using recursion, at the moment this code is never executed:

```
  if ( is_array($content) ) {
    $output = str_repeat("--", $depth);
    foreach ( $content as $part ) {
      $output .= tag($tag, $part);
    }
    $depth--;
    return $output;
  }
```

Comment: Are you positive? I added `echo __LINE__ . "\n";` and got ```tag: 'td', depth: 1
tag: 'td', depth: 2
15
tag: 'td', depth: 2
15
```, 15 being the line just under `$output .= tag($tag, $part);`

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong about that, it's not *never* executed, but not in the sense it seems to be designed for. `$content` is always an array of strings that have been generated by *previous* calls to `tag()`, never an array of arrays. So, `tag()` is called twice for the table elements.